# Proving a linear algebra equivalence statement

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-optimization

[image]

The equation in the link above is from Boyd's Convex Optimization class. How is the last equality derived?

Comment: This would be the equality case of the triangle inequality if $P_i$ were required to be full rank.  But since none of the quoted material requires that $(P_i u)^T x$ is ever parallel to $\overline{a}_i^T x -b_i$, the last line should be an "$\leq$".

Comment: @EricTowers did you see the sup? The equality holds. The proof is highly similar to the one without absolute values.

Comment: @LinAlg : Why do you think the subspace spanned by a $P_i$ with a nontrivial nullspace includes the parallel direction?  It is straightforward to make that subspace perpendicular.

Comment: @EricTowers Please provide a counterexample (or write out the proof in just a few lines taking $u=\pm(P^Tx)/||P^Tx||$).

Comment: @LinAlg : Set $b_i = 0$ and let the column space of $P_i$ be any basis of $a_i^\perp$ union a zero vector.  Then $(P_i u)^T x \perp a_i^T x - b_i$ for all $x$.

Comment: @EricTowers For two scalars to be perpendicular, one needs to be 0. It seems to me that $P_i^Tx=0$ in your counterexample. Then the equality in the question still holds, right?

Comment: @LinAlg : Why do you think $x$ is a vector?  There's no way to tell from what is provided that $x$ is not a scalar or a scalar parameter, or even a rank 2 tensor...

Comment: @EricTowers I know $x$ is a real vector from the context. The teaching materials of Boyd are well known.

Comment: @LinAlg : Then we've made it back to my first comment: "... none of the quoted material ..." declares the types of anything other than $P_i$, making the question incomplete.